# Total dinâmico de acordo com o NumberPicker Android

Tags: android, edittext, textview

Estou usando NumberPicker para que o usuário selecione a quantidade. Cada numberpicker tem um total que já aparece na tela de acordo com a quantidade selecionada pelo usuário.

Exemplo: 
NumberPicker 1 = qnt 3  =  R$ 15,00

NumberPicker 2 = qnt 2 = R$10,00

NumberPicker 3 = qnt 4  = R$8,00

O total de cada item está dinâmico, assim que muda a quantidade já mostra o valor total na frente.

Estou empacado no total geral. Esse total geral pegaria todos os totais e somaria e retornaria um total geral dinâmico.

Abaixo os ouvintes do Numberpickers

```
np_Garrafa.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int numEscolhido) {

            qntGarrafa = numEscolhido;
            total_Garrafa = qntGarrafa * 10;
            txt_totalGarrafa.setText("R$ " + total_Garrafa);
            Log.i("garrafa", String.valueOf(qntGarrafa));
        }
    });

    np_Garrafao10.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int numEscolhido) {

            qntGarrafao10 = numEscolhido;
            total_Garrafao10 = qntGarrafao10 * 5;
            txt_totalGarrafao10.setText("R$ " + total_Garrafao10);
            Log.i("garrafa10", String.valueOf(qntGarrafao10));

        }
    });

    np_Garrafao20.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int numEscolhido) {

            qntGarrafao20 = numEscolhido;
            total_Garrafao20 = qntGarrafao20 * 10;
            txt_totalGarrafao20.setText("R$ " + total_Garrafao20);
            Log.i("garrafa20", String.valueOf(qntGarrafao20));

        }
    });
```

Tentei colocar em cada ouvinte um variável que receberia o total de cada item e exibir no textview total geral. Porém se usuário diminuir a quantidade ele ainda continua somando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

voce poderia tentar algo assim ó:

```
float totalGeral = 0.0f;
// cria uma variável total geral
np_Garrafa.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int numEscolhido) {
        qntGarrafa = numEscolhido;
        total_Garrafa = qntGarrafa * 10;
        totalGeral+=total_Garrafa;
        // soma o q tem na garrafa ao total geral
        txt_totalGarrafa.setText("R$ " + total_Garrafa);
        Log.i("garrafa", String.valueOf(qntGarrafa));
    }
});

np_Garrafao10.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int numEscolhido) {
        qntGarrafao10 = numEscolhido;
        total_Garrafao10 = qntGarrafao10 * 5;
        totalGeral+=total_Garrafa10;
        // soma o q jah tem no totalGeral + garrafa10
        txt_totalGarrafao10.setText("R$ " + total_Garrafao10);
        Log.i("garrafa10", String.valueOf(qntGarrafao10));

    }
});

np_Garrafao20.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int numEscolhido) {

        qntGarrafao20 = numEscolhido;
        total_Garrafao20 = qntGarrafao20 * 10;
        totalGeral+=total_Garrafa20;
        // soma o q jah tem no toalGeral + o que tem na garrafa20
        txt_totalGarrafao20.setText("R$ " + total_Garrafao20);
        Log.i("garrafa20", String.valueOf(qntGarrafao20));

    }
});
// dai
txt_totalGeral.SetText("R$ " + totalGeral);
```

espero que funcione.

avisa ai se deu certo

Comment: usei o que você colocou e apliquei em outro método. Assim que o usuário adicionar ao carrinho ele faz a soma total e já exibe, ficou bem mais prático. Obrigado